# $cond in mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume I have something like
(I know the example query is not logical, but I tried to minimize the situation)

```
for(var j=0; j < 3; j++){
  db.collection.update({name: "alex"}, {surname: "brown"})
}
```

Here is my question. If `j=2` I want to increment document's age.

To do this I wrote;

```
for(var j=0; j < 3; j++){
  if(j !==2){
    db.collection.update({name: "alex"}, {surname: "brown"})
  }else{
   db.collection.update({name: "alex"}, {surname: "brown" , $inc: { age: 1}})
  }
}
```

How can I do this by using `$cond` or `if/else condition` in a more practical way in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

`$cond` is only used in aggregations, thus it won't help you achieve your goal.

a more elegant way to do that might be:

```
var update = {
    surname: "brown"
}

for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  if(j === 2){
    update["$inc"] = { age: 1 }
  }

   db.collection.update({name: "alex"}, update)
  }
}
```